# QProgressBar / styleSheet изменить цвет

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qss

Хочу сделать красный прогрес бар, в случаи неудачи. Как это сделать?
Самое красивое что нашел в примере ниже. Тут изменяется геометрия, размер рамок, и прогресс бар накладывается на процент, и процент меняется на 100.

Думаю, если бы мне написали как у QT написан стиль, я бы смог изменить только цвет на красный, и остальное меня устроило бы.

```
if (!m_executor->is_ok()) {
    ui->progressBar->setFormat("error");
    ui->progressBar->setStyleSheet("QProgressBar{"
                                   "border: 1px solid transparent;text-align: right;"
                                   "color:rgba(255,255,250,255);"
                                   "border-radius: 5px;"
                                   "border-width: 3px;"
                                   "border-image: 9,2,5,2; "
                                   "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 200), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 200));"
                                    "}"
                                   "QProgressBar::chunk {background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 rgba(255,200,0,255), stop: 1 rgba(255,0,0,255));}");
}
```

[image: example]
[image: default]

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qprogressbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можешь попробовать не ssc кодами (*странно, я думал ssc отработает*)

А так вот код :

```
ui->progressBar->setStyleSheet("color: red;"
                               "background-color: yellow;"
                               "selection-background-color: red;");
//selection-background-color - цвет главной линии
// color - цвет текста
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вот так ??

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
ui->progressBar->setFormat("error");
ui->progressBar->setValue(92);
ui->progressBar->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter); // смешно я долго не понимал почему не отрабатывает, только потом догадался css разметку глянуть :3
ui->progressBar->setStyleSheet("QProgressBar{"
                               "border: 1px solid transparent;text-align: center;" // было right
                               "color:rgba(255,255,250,255);"
                               "border-radius: 5px;"
                               "border-width: 3px;"
                               "border-image: 9,2,5,2; "
                               "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 200), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 200));"
                                "}"
                               "QProgressBar::chunk {background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 rgba(255,100,0,255), stop: 1 rgba(255,0,0,255));}");
```

Изменил только две вещи :

1. поменял оранжевый цвет `rgba(255,200,0,255)` на красный `rgba(255,100,0,255)`
2. центрировал надпись `text-align: center;`

Для понимания, пользуясь CSS разметкой для изменения виджетов, надо понимать что весь функционал CSS разметки Qt не поддерживает. И по этому "стандартная зелёная переливающаяся линия", есть верх реализации QProgressBar-а, Просто взять и поменять цвет при этом чтобы "переливы" остались у меня такое не вышло.

Также упомяну вашу проблему более точно, как я понял у вас не хватило знаний как поменять цветовую гамму, вы не поняли что пользуетесь цветовой моделью RGBa `rgba(255,100,0,255)` , но это поправимо :)

```
rgba(255,100,0,255) == rgba(красный, зеленый, синий, прозрачность) 
// чем выше прозрачность тем более отчётливо видим
```

*оранжевый получили благодаря "смеси" красного(3/5) и зелёного (2/5).*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: кроме цвета текста ничего не поменялось (windows)

Comment: @KtoTo ОК, буду дома попробую на винде. _А так по правде говоря странно , в обще ваш пример лично по мне должен был отработать , (не помню точно но возможно эти элементы отрисованы CSS но в Qt он сильно обрезан !!! помни об этом )_

Comment: может я плохо высказался, оранжевый прогресс бар рисует. Но рисует кроме того что криво, но и очень оторвано от дизайна системы. Мне бы гармонично нужно нарисовать.